# Patterns on melted, then solidified chocolate

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, physical-chemistry, food

### Observation

I have melted some chocolate (in a bain-marie, or water-bath) in a bowl, and then turned off the stove. I let the hot and liquid chocolate stand there, letting it cool for a few hours at room temperature. Then (it was solid, albeit not very hard) I covered it with aluminium foil, and put it in the fridge (ca $6^\circ\,\mathrm{C}$). When I took it out the next day, I saw those patterns that *look* like tiny footprints. Each "track" was about $2$-$4\,\mathrm{mm}$ wide.
The arrow indicates where I pulled out the spoon, which left a little cusp. Note how the "footprints" converge there. The bowl is about $15\,\mathrm{cm}$ in diameter.

[image: patterns_on_chocolate]

### Possible causes that are unlikely

**Insect Footprints.** Even though it looks a lot like it, I think that insect footprints are an unlikely cause, though, for the following reasons:

1. It's deep winter where I live, and there has not been any fly or similar large insect in my flat for months.
2. The patterns were not visible before I put the chocolate in the fridge, and it's even more unlikely that an insect lives inside the fridge at those low temperatures (most insects lose the ability to move, and eventually die).
3. Other people have observed the exact same phenomenon, see [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbUHo.jpg)](https://www.gutefrage.net/frage/hilfe-sind-das-tierspuren) and [[2]](https://www.principia-magazin.de/muster/258-perlenketten-das-muster-des-monats-02-2015/). In [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbUHo.jpg), a pastry chef claims that he has seen this before, and that he rules out insects.

But I cannot be $100\,\%$ sure, since I have not watched it all the time.

**Droplets falling from the aluminium foil.** Since the foil has inevitable crinkles, a possibility would be that small droplets would fall from those crinkles onto the chocolate, causing regular patterns. However, this would not explain why there always are two parallel rows of droplets (which also appear in very regular "step-widths").

### Question

What causes those patterns? Based on my considerations so far, I am inclined to think that this is a Physics phenomenon, which has to do with how chocolate solidifies, or how the "dew" on the surface forms. However, I am aware that most times when people report patterns on the surface of cooled-down chocolate it looks more crystalline, for example [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/408610/melted-chocolate-forming-fractal-branches), and that this looks nothing like it. Overall, I am very unsure about where to place this.

*Comment*: This is *not* a cooking-related question - it is to understand which physical processes produce such patterns in a substance like chocolate.

Comment: Just a speculation - there is probably some convection in the melted chocolate which could segregate some of the components of the chocolate (fats?) and collect them near the lines where there is less movement. Maybe this also introduces some stress in the solid chocolate.

Comment: That's a very interesting idea. However, the patterns extend to the sides of the bowl, where the chocolate is very thin. I presume that for this to work, the convection cells would have to be very small, and happen only in a very thin layer.

Comment: Just to seek clarification, did you have the chocolate hot and melted when you began cooling it? If so, then the uneven heat transfer from the solid-solid and air-liquid contact could possibly account for the presence of currents when the substance started cooling.

Comment: Yes (I have tried to add clarifications in my post). However, the first cooling phase (at room temperature) was relatively gentle, since the bowl remained in the warm water (which cooled down as well).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [cooking.se].

Comment: I understand that classification is not obvious for this question - however, it falls into the same category as [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/408610/melted-chocolate-forming-fractal-branches) post about patterns on chocolate. I.m.o. it is not cooking-related, but about the Physics that might create such patterns.

Comment: @KyleKanos - This is very much a physics question, since it deals with pattern formation during phase interactions. The light brown surface cover is clearly a phase I or II crystal phase of the cocoa fat (a bloom), likely on top of some of the more high-melting phases. But the formation of that phase may well introduce instabilities. I suspect we are better able to figure it out than Seasoned Advice, since the main goal over there would be to just get a nice shiny phase V.

Comment: Could it be something related to the hydrophobic nature of fats in chocolates, forming thin layers, like in cell membranes? Nice question anyway. I guess I'll melt some chocolate tonight

Comment: I don't know why you get lines, but I can speculate about why the lines become dots. Chocolate contains oil. If you have a line of oil in a watery environment, you might find the oil gathers into droplets because oil molecules repel water molecules and attract other oil molecules.

Comment: This seems to be some kind of sugar bloom, but  very interesting patterns: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chocolate_bloom

Comment: @DominikS For scale, could you please tell us the diameter of the bowl and the width of the tracks?

Comment: Good point, @DavidBailey, thanks. I have added it in the post.

Comment: It's clearly tiny leprechaun footprints

Answer (score 2):

Understanding this in detail could probably take you from a science fair project to a PhD, but my best guess is that these are chocolate [sugar blooms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chocolate_bloom#Sugar_bloom) preferentially forming on vortex streets that were distorted and then frozen into the chocolate on cooling.

Sugar blooms form in chocolate when exposed to moisture, and they often occur when chocolate is [stored in a refrigerator](https://www.chocolatetemperingmachines.com/pages/what-is-chocolate-bloom).
Since chocolate is a [complex emulsion](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/chapters/mono/10.1201/b16546-17/chocolate-manufacturing-processing-technology-emmanuel-ohene-afoakwa), exactly were the blooms nucleate may depend on slight variations in the local physical and chemical makeup of the chocolate.

If you look closely at the tracks in the image above, as well as the images cited in the question as well as others that can be found on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/microbiology/comments/p9dipv/just_a_quick_question_does_this_look_like/?rdt=33757) or [elsewhere](http://www.candyexperiments.com/2012/07/summer-chocolate-blooming.html), you will notice that the spots are not side by side in the tracks, but instead alternate  - left, right, left, right, … - as you go along the tracks.  This immediately makes me think of a [Karmen vortex-street](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n_vortex_street), similar to this image by [Jürgen Wagner from Wikpedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Karmansche_Wirbelstr_gro%C3%9Fe_Re.JPG)

[image: Vortex shedding made visible by smoke]

Such a vortex street could form in the chocolate as eddies are [shed on alternate sides of a stirring stick](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:FIV_cylindre.gif):

[image: Vortex shedding gif]

If the chocolate make-up, temperature, cooling rate, and stirring mechanics are just right, the centre of each eddy could slightly concentrate sugar or create a physical difference in the chocolate. Each "defect" could then be the nucleus for a bloom when the chocolate is subsequently stored in the cool damp environment of a refrigerator. Depending on the how the chocolate was stirred, a complex network of tracks could then become visible. It makes sense that some of the tracks converge where the spoon pulled out, since it is presumably the movement of the spoon that created the vortex streets.

To confirm (or not) this hypothesis would require some careful experimentation. I can't do it myself because my home science Health and Safety Committee (i.e. my spouse) is concerned that I would eat all the experiments with serious detrimental consequences for my weight and blood pressure.

Comment: If an experimenter could get approval from their HSC, they might try to induce *particular* patterns in the chocolate by carefully choosing a final stir pattern. For instance, instead of a circular bowl as shown, they might use a rectangular dish, with the final stir in some sort of wide grid.

Comment: alternate objects make me thing at footprint when I walk in the sand, but I'm quite sure that has nothing to do with the pattern formed in the chocolate. I'm downvoting

Comment: @basics The reason for your downvote is unclear. If you believe it is unlikely that the tracks are due to frozen vortex streets, it would be great if you could explain your reasoning.

Comment: the burden of proof is up to who's trying to provide a convincing answer. To cut a long story short: in that desperate answer, what is the source of the frozen vortices? are they freezing immediately altogether? no vortex diffusion in the perpendicular direction with respect to the main flow? This answer smells like sh*t, and those are among the reasons I'm downvoting

Comment: @basics Okay, there clearly is not going to be a productive exchange here.

Comment: if you think so, take that answer as a good answer then

Answer (score 1):

I think three things are playing important role here,

- grain structure of chocolate surface
- sugar bloom
- fat bloom
- solubility of fat in water

Let me present my hypothesis

Due to cooling two things happened i) moisture evaporated from surface ii) surface started to solidify forming [grains](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grain_boundary).

[image: grains]
That's how grains look

Now sugar bloom happens when water get evaporated and sugar crystals remain on surface, the white part on surface of chocolate is sugar bloom. Fat bloom happens when fat underneath the surface gets up on the surface through porous region and accumulates there. The grain boundaries served as path for fat to travel up and it got accumulated near the grain boundaries. The pattern formed is very similar to grain structure. The dark part is fat.

Let's clear some questions.

Why are the patches round?
Because fat is insoluble in water hence forms a sphere (cohesive forces win over adhesive forces etc.). That gives the circular shape to them.

Why they appear like footprint?
They don't! Zoom the image in question there are multiple dots scattered randomly on trails (grain boundaries). They are more like Milky Way appearing in night sky.

Why pattern is formed on walls of container?
Chocolate used maybe rich in fat hence the thin layer was sufficient to provide enough fat.

If someone can film timelapse of chocolate cooling down then we can get evidence. Also leaving the chocolate harden fully can expose grain structure.